# Obtain an interactive command's output during interaction

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have a dictionary program, `sdcv`, that outputs either normal text or HTML, and I'm writing a Bash script that normalizes the output so that it simply prints stdout if `sdcv` is writing normal text or it prints formatted HTML using `lynx` if `sdcv` is outputting HTML.

For that purpose, I'm trying to make a Bash script I can pipe to using `sdcv MYWORD | myscript.sh` that will analyze `sdcv`'s output. The problem is that `sdcv` has two outputs, and I need to format the second one on the basis of the first one. After the first output, `sdcv` requires user input, and then prints the second output.

I've tried using `FIRST_OUTPUT=$(tee /dev/tty)`, but the problem is that this amalgamates `sdcv`'s first output, my input requested by `sdcv`, and `sdcv`'s second output, and I don't have access to anything until I've entered the input.

How could I proceed?

Comment: [`expect`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/expect5.31/expect.1.html) maybe.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski woah, that is an extremely handy program! thank you very much!

Comment: If you want something post-processable, maybe use its `-j` option.

Comment: So you want the "Found NN items, similar to WORD. .... Your choice" as input one and the result of choice as input two?

Comment: If you only want part two you can set your script as pager. Typically `SDCV_PAGER=./my_script sdcv WORD` the script will get the result as stdin, - but from what you write it sounds like you want both. Is this correct?

Comment: @ibuprofen right, the initial ideal was to analyze part one in order to know how to properly handle part two, if there is a part two at all. I will investigate the pager suggestion, thank you!

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas unfortunately, wrt. to the `-j` option, it works only if the dictionary's entries are not themselves in HTML, which is my case here. The `-n` option might be promising however

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can just pipe the sequences of lines that start with `<html...` and end with `</html...`  to that `lynx` (or  maybe better `elinks` or `w3m`) command.

Like:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl
while (<<>>) {
  if (!$inhtml && m{<html}i) {
    $inhtml = 1;
    open HTML, "|-", qw(elinks -dump);
  }

  print {$inhtml ? HTML : STDOUT}  $_;

  if ($inhtml && m{</html}i) {
    close HTML;
    $inhtml = 0;
  }
}
```

(and `sdcv MYWORD | that-script`)

Comment: Unfortunately I still need to handle the input prompt!

Answer (score 0):

This ended working for me, the answer was a painful journey through expect. I have no doubt there's room for improving this code, so feel free to leave your suggestions!

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

set arg1 [lindex $argv 0]
spawn sdcv $arg1

expect "Found*" {

    expect "Your choice*" {
        expect_user -re "(.*)\n"

        set user_input $expect_out(0,string)
        send "$user_input\r"

        expect "#"
        set output $expect_out(buffer)

        set command "echo \"$output\" | lynx --dump --stdin"

        spawn bash
        expect "*"

        send "$command\r"
        expect "$command\r\n"

        expect eof
    }

    #for some reason gets saved to expect_out(0,string) when we input a word with a single match
    set output $expect_out(0,string)
    set command "echo \"$output\" | lynx --dump --stdin"

    spawn bash

    send "$command\r"
    expect "$command\r\n"

    expect eof
}
```

Comment: Update a day later: for me, the Python pexpect library is considerably more intuitive and easier to use, and achieves the same result